# Looking for a good x86 assembler and disassembler library

Tags: x86, assembly, polymorphism, disassembly

I'm writing a polymorphic engine for a security related project, I need to programtically identify x86 code and identify patterns in it. BeaEngine is awesome, the only thing is, I'm not sure if it can convert the mnemonics back into opcodes and assemble different instructions.

The question is, *does anyone know of something similar to beaengine but can also assemble***?** Thanks.

Comment: I don't see your other question in your profile. Hold on while I sanitize this one...

Comment: Does it have to be a single library? AsmJit (http://code.google.com/p/asmjit/) can do the assembly

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered GNU binutils?  It might not be advertised as having a stable API, but IME it's stable enough for an in-house product that you can maintain when needed.  I've often  wanted to build a human-assisted decompiler (but it's less and less relevant every year) and the binutils libraries seem to have all the parts I'd need.  I wouldn't need an assembler, but that too should be reasonably easy to access programmatically.  (I don't think assembly is an explicitly available API in binutils, but it's Free Software, so you get to *make* it into the library you want.)